# Does the redeemer have to be from a wallet address/contract?

Tags: plutus, wallet, smart-contract, haskell, redeemer

Could a contract be programmed such that the redeemer seemingly comes from nowhere from what the node / someone monitoring the blockchain could tell? I am thinking if you gave the contract some ada and had it pay fees automatically out of itself, you could run totally anonymous logic. Are there restrictions preventing you from doing this?

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be misunderstanding how smart contracts work on Cardano.

> Does the redeemer have to be from a wallet address(?)

Redeemers don't come from wallet address, they are included on transactions. And transactions must be created by a user off-chain.

> I am thinking if you gave the contract some ada and had it pay fees automatically out of itself...

There is no such thing as automated smart contracts in Cardano. The datums at script address *only* change state as a result of a transaction submitted from off-chain.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine how you'd do that.  The validation nodes control fee distribution, only relying on the TX to provide the fees, but not relying on the TX to tell them how/where to distribute them.

Comment: I was thinking since in the eUXTO model the redeemer is arbitrary, you could pass unit () as the redeemer. The validation script could be programmed to always accept () and pay a small amount of fee to the node, and the rest to some value in the datum. This is how I would do it in my head, but I don't know if Plutus actually allows this.